# VBA macro to change color of cells in range when a cell is selected

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write code that will, when a user selects a cell within a range, change the color of all the cells in that range.  When running the code posted below, i get an error "Object doesn't support this property or method".  I noticed that if i edit the code to just paste a "1" in all the cells that it works just fine.  What am I doing incorrectly?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Excel.range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, range("G1:I5")) Is Nothing Then
        For Each cell In range("G1:I5")
        cell.interier.ColorIndex = 10
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: you spelled interior wrong

Comment: well that's embarrassing...Shouldn't have dropped spelling in 3rd grade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is simply a typo of `Interior`

```
...
cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 10
'#         ^  
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be aware that you do not have to loop over the cells:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Range("G1:I5")
    If Intersect(r, Target) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    r.Interior.ColorIndex = 10
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks!  I always appreciate efficiency improvements.